# Subsets and Cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm confused on if I should count a subset as one element or if I should count all the elements of that subset when computing cardinality.

Example:

Given the set $A = \{1,2,3,\{4,5,6\}\}$ does $A$ have a cardinality of $4$ (using the convention where I count the subset as just one element) or does it have a cardinality of $6$ (Counting all the elements of the subset towards my cardinality)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case that you bring $\{4,5,6\}$ is **not a subset** of $\{1,2,3,\{4,5,6\}\}$. It is an element of that set.

To make matters easier, assign a letter to that set, $B=\{4,5,6\}$. Now we have that $A=\{1,2,3,B\}$. Clearly $B\nsubseteq A$ since no element of $B$ is an element of $A$. So $A$ has exactly four elements.

Answer (score 5):

It has cardinality $4$. Despite the fact that it is itself a set, $\{4,5,6\}$ is only one element in $\{1,2,3,\{4,5,6\}\}$.